# Powershell find a value and assign it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do this and can't see what's wrong. No errors. It should print yyyy.

```
$test = "a.z"

$list = @{
    az = @{
        qq = "yyyy";
        ww = "uuuu";
    }
    bz = @{
        qq = "eeee";
        ww = "rrrr";
    }
}

$finalarray = $list | where ($_ -eq $test.replace('.',''))

Write-Host ("$($finalarray.qq)")

#should print yyyy
```

Comment: Change the line `$finalarray = $list | where ($_ -eq $test.replace('.',''))` to `$finalarray = $list[$test.replace('.','')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@{}` literal construct you use to define your `$list` variable is a `[hashtable]`, not a list type.

Fortunately, you can index into hashtables by key name, so you can simplify your logic significantly:

```
$test = "a.z"

$list = @{
    az = @{
        qq = "yyyy";
        ww = "uuuu";
    }
    bz = @{
        qq = "eeee";
        ww = "rrrr";
    }
}

$finalArray = $list[$test.Replace('.', '')]

Write-Host $finalArray.qq
```

You can read more about these wonderful data structures in the [`about_Hash_Tables` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables)

Comment: thanks a lot. i'm new to powershell. got confused there

Comment: @EricKlaus yeah the initial learning curve can be a bit steep, I've added a link to the builtin help documentation on hash tables